# displayStack function printing random letters

Tags: c, data-structures

I am trying to create a Stack using an Array. I have made all the necessary functions and I have no errors in the console.

however the output from the `printf` in the `displayStack()` is

```
ê    @² ` Ç      i   i     q @╨ @. ` Ç   x
```

how can i fix it ?

my code is :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>


struct Stack {

    int top;
    char  array[];// Array for stack which will store the operators from infx

};

void createStack(struct Stack st){
st.top=-1;
}

void push(struct Stack st,char ch)
{
st.top++;
st.array[st.top]=ch;
}
void displayStack(struct Stack st){
    int i;
    for (i=st.top;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%c\n",st.array[i]);
    }
}
char pop(struct Stack st){
    char x='x';
    if(st.top<0){
        printf("Stack UnderFlow\n");
    }else{
        x= st.array[st.top];
        st.top--;
    }
    return x;
}

int main()
{
struct Stack st;
createStack(st);
push(st,'x');
push(st,'x');
push(st,'x');
push(st,'x');
push(st,'x');
push(st,'x');

displayStack(st);
pop(st);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Where's declared and/or allocated the dimension of `st.array`? :)

Answer (score 1):

Here:

```
struct Stack {
    int top;
    char  array[];
};
```

`array` can be used as a [flexible array member](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Flexible_array_member), but you need to `malloc` with the size of the `struct` + the number of elements you want to use in the array, i.e.:

```
data = malloc(sizeof(*data) + nelements);
```

otherwise the compiler doesn't know how many elements you want to associate to the array

Comment: can you explain a bit more please

Comment: @LakshaySethi of course, when you define `struct Stack st;` the compiler doesn't reserve space for the array (because it doesn't know how many elements are used at runtime), you need to specify the size using dynamyc memory, another option is using a pointer (`char *` instead of `char[]`) and reserve space for the pointer itself.

Comment: thank you for your reply,I am trying not to use pointers to have a better understanding of why we use them. I am not sure how to specify the size for char array[] using dynamic memory. where do you mean we need to use the `data = malloc(sizeof(*data) + nelements);`